# NetworkManager problem with dns servers

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, resolvconf

I've got two network cards, one is onboard and the other is an added PCI card.
I also created a bridge interface for my KVM virtual machines to use, so my desktop (host) uses the **enp3s0** interface and the VMs (guests) use the **enp4s3** interface through a bridge that I created named VM-NetBridge. Here's the ip a command:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:5a:3a:0b:43:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.35/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::325a:3aff:fe0b:431b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp4s6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master VM-NetBridge state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:7d:75:cd:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::2e0:7dff:fe75:cdd7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: VM-NetBridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:7d:75:cd:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.110/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global VM-NetBridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e0:7dff:fe75:cdd7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:82:71:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr1-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:55:a9:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master VM-NetBridge state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:bf:f8:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now, I'm having a problem with nameservers: every time I boot I have to delete a file and update resolvconf.
I made a script with this:

```
#! /bin/zsh

if [ -f /run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager ]; then
    sudo rm /run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager
    sudo resolvconf -u
fi
```

This solves the problem, but I don't know why this file (`NetworkManager`) is automatically created on `/run/resolvconf/interface/` and how to avoid that.

I also cannot configure the second network card, because it shows me it is 'not managed'.

[snapshot NetworkManager applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ViI.png)